# what is the issue with elements align

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a search box like this:

[image]

as you see I cant set them align at all.

the real problem is, I cant set align in all browser. for example: I have to put `2px top in chrome` and `3px top in ff`

how can I do that:

here is [jfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UgN84/)

css:

```
.home_kadr { padding:10px; text-align:center;}
.home_search {
    font-size:16px!important;
    font-family:Arial!important;
    font-style:italic!important;
    padding:14px!important;
    border:1px solid #d6bf99!important;
    border-radius:2px!important;
    margin:0px!important;
    /*border-right:none!important;*/
    border-top-right-radius:0px!important;
    border-bottom-right-radius:0px!important;
}
.home_btn {
    width:115px; height:42px;
    background:url(../images/home_search.png);
    display:inline-block;
    font-family:'b koodak';
    font-size:20px;
    padding:8px 8px 0px 8px;
    color:#FFF;
    text-align:center;
    border:none;
}
```

html:

```
    <div class="home_kadr">
        <div class="home_btn">جستجو</div><input type="text" name="fld_domainName" id="fld_domainName" class="wd-300 en home_search" />
    </div>
```

Comment: can you create a fiddle ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See here is the updated [Link to jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jvaibhav/UgN84/1/).

This may be solve your problem for every browser.

Changes are:

```
 .home_kadr{
 display:inline-block;
 }

 .home_search {
 float:left;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Float the text field and the submit button in order to align them.

Answer (score 0):

make the following changes to the css:

```
.home_search {
  float: right;
}

.home_btn {
  /* display: inline-block; */
  float: right;
}
```

finally add the following element as last child of  `<div class="home_kadr">`:

```
<div style="clear: both; "></div>
```